# using FlexboxLayout in each other is slow in iOS

Tags: nativescript

I have a lot of FlexLayout element in my template and it is so slow on iOS devices.
i replaced that with StackLayout and now it became little fast than before.

I'd like to know which Layout Container is fastest layout in `Nativescript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is never one right solution for all various needs, which is why we always have options and that applies to layouts in {N} too.

Learn more about layouts interactively at [nslayouts.com](https://www.nslayouts.com/) and choose the one that suits your use case.

If you show use what exactly you are trying to achieve, we may able to give you some suggestion. There are some general guidelines you may have to follow for better performance,

1. Avoid nested layouts
2. Use GridLayout when you need known number of partitions in your UI, the less the number of partitions are, the better the performance would be. Use FlexboxLayout otherwise.
3. If you just want to stack items in vertical or horizontal order, StackLayout may be a good option. Use FlexboxLayout only when you want to use flex box specific features, like when items has to be wrapped to next line, change order of items etc.,
4. Try to not use StackLayouts just for the shake of borders around, since you can add border to the component itself.
5. If you have really complicated heavy UI components, you may load it once the page has completed navigation, that may be faster.
6. Prefer ListView over Repeater / for loop as much as possible.

By following the above at least I can confirm, I don't hit performance issues in my apps where I have 100s of elements and 10s of partitions on screen. If you still face issues, try creating a Playground example where we can see the issue.

Comment: thank u. after seeing nslayouts.com i understand that should change many of layouts

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this same thing with FlexboxLayouts on IOS where I was doing animations with the layouts.  It worked great on Android, but was very slow on IOS.  I switched it to a GridLayout, and things worked a lot better.